# TightVNC server not getting right-clicks from Mac Screen Sharing/VNC client?

Tags: mac, vnc, screen-sharing, right-click

I am using Apple's Screen Sharing client in OS X 10.6.2, to connect to TightVNC running on Win XP. But TightVNC is not receiving right-clicks.

Scaling is on, and everything else is working fine. I do not think it is a problem with the server because a friend was over and was able to send right-clicks to my server using a RealVNC client.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct solution, but the work around I used was to press:

```
shift + fn + f10
```

Which is equivalent to right clicking the selected item.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, right-clicks from the client are sent to the remote computer.

(But something tells me you're having trouble with that? What does Ctrl-Click give you? Which VNC server are you using on the Windows machine? [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) gives me no issues. Are you scaling the screen? Is everything else working fine?)

Comment: I am using TightVNC on the xp box.  Scaling on.  Everything else working fine.  I do not think it is a problem with the server because a friend was over and was able to send right-clicks to my server using RealVNC.

Comment: And Ctrl-click? (I guess that is sent exactly the same as right-click, but one never knows...)

Comment: I am on a Macbook.  I've actually only tried Ctrl-Click.  I haven't tried hooking up an external mouse but I would imagine it would act the same.

Comment: Two finger-tap then? (Again, this is probably the same, but one never knows, especially as maybe the Ctrl is sent to the Win XP box...). And what if you disable scaling for testing?